# Found a PHP function for absolute path and curious exactly how it works

Tags: php

```
function findRoot() {
    return(substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], 0, (stripos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])+1));
}
```

The function simply returns the absolute path of the server; however, I'm not sure exactly how it is working.  Before using any code, I like to understand exactly how it works so I can better understand and implement the script.

Can someone please explain how it works.  I've used substr() before; however, never anything to this extent.

Any suggestions to improving the script is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]
```

Contains the path of the script relative to the root. The server calls PHP like `php relative/path.php` from the server root; this is that name of the script with a `/`; basically, a link with this URL leads to the same page.

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
```

Contains the absolute path of the script. This is resolved by PHP.

```
stripos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])+1
```

The position of the relative path inside the absolute path. Taking this many characters from the absolute filename wouldn't include the trailing `/`, so 1 is added.

```
substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], 0, (stripos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])+1))
```

The part of the absolute filename before the relative path; the amount of characters from the absolute filename calculated in the previous step. This must be the root, as the relative filename is relative to the server root.

Comment: is this an okay method to use for retrieving absolute path?  I like to use absolute path for my includes instead of having to worry about relative paths.  I looked into __DIR__, but it gets more complicating when having to worry about including it in multiple directories.  I was trying to find a better solution to replace $_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'] which I am no longer using.

Comment: I forgot to comment out the code.  I looked into `__DIR__`*

Answer (score 0):

By limiting one operation by line, it makes it easier to understand the code.
Here's almost the same function, with additional details and echos:

```
function find_absolute_path() {
    $strScriptFilename          = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
    $strScriptName              = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
    // stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string.
    // int stripos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
    $intPositionOfName          = stripos($strScriptFilename, $strScriptName);
    // substr — Return part of a string.
    // string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
    $strWwwPathWithoutName  = substr($strScriptFilename, 0,($intPositionOfName + 1));

    echo "strScriptFilename: " . $strScriptFilename . "<br/>";
    echo "strScriptName: " . $strScriptName . "<br/>";
    echo "intPositionOfName: " . $intPositionOfName . "<br/>";
    echo "strWwwPathWithoutName: " . $strWwwPathWithoutName . "<br/>";

    return  $strWwwPathWithoutName;
} // find_absolute_path

$strAbsolutePath    = find_absolute_path();
echo "strWebPath: " . $strAbsolutePath;
```

You'll notice how the script is removing $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] from the absolute path, leaving the path to the web server.

Comment: is this a better method than the method I used in my question?  If so, what makes this one better besides explaining whats happening inside the script?

Comment: oh okay.  Thanks for the honesty.  I really wasn't sure exactly which method was better.  I'm assuming they are doing the exact same thing so they are prob about the same.  But I will def. read through yours more closely just to get some ideas.  Thanks :)