# Which is the best method for getting absolute path of server

Tags: php

I have two options right now that I am working with to get absolute path of the server.  My main concerns are speed and stability of the server.  I am trying to find a method to replace $_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as I am no longer using this method.

I am not only trying to find a solution to a problem, but also trying to learn in the process.  I asked a previous question on StackOverflow to find out exactly how the first method was actually being processed to learn more about that ([Found a PHP function for absolute path and curious exactly how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517039/found-a-php-function-for-absolute-path-and-curious-exactly-how-it-works)), and now I am trying to find out if it is the best option or if there are better options.

I am open for input for even better solutions if you have any as well.

**First method:**

```
function findRoot() {
    return(substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], 0, (stripos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])+1));
```

}

**Second method:**

```
echo realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

I have never used either method on a live server to test stability, so I was hoping to get some input from others.  Advantages and Disadvantages would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found that option as well.  The only problem that I found with using these is when moving into other directories.  It can get rather complex in a large backend system.  Am I misinformed on this?  I like to use absolute paths for all of my includes.  This is why I am looking into absolute path.

Comment: its just my very quick in passing suggestion. I'm not saying its better or worse than your ideas

Comment: You are correct. Both `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` will have the full path to the file calling the constant. This means if you are calling the constant from inside a included file that is under a sub-directory, it will include that sub-directory. Really, the only *best* way is to just set a constant/variable at the top level and refer to that. Most larger programs do this as it is the most reliable way to find the actual document root. Usually this is set in an installer. I generally bootstrap all my apps and just set a constant there.

Comment: such as  $rootDir = __DIR__; set in a file in the top level directory, and include that file on each page.  Then just refer to $rootDir from that point on?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, I generally bootstrap my apps meaning that all requests are funneled through a single script that handles routing using mod_rewrite. I just set that stuff up in there as every script in the app will go through that single script that does all the including. You are probably already including a single file on every page like a connection.php or config.php or similar. You can just set a constant/variable in there.

Comment: can you give an example script or page that explains what you do (bootstrapping)?  I am always up for learning new methods.  I understand about using the variable in every include...no need to explain that.  Post this in an answer if you will so that I can accept yours as answer since you explained all of this to me.

Comment: I generally write a new setup based on what I'm doing. I just add a .htaccess file with `RewriteRule (.*) index.php` in the root of my app. That will route all requests, whether the page exists or not to index.php. Then I setup a few variables, include a config file, connect to db and stuff like that. Then parse the url to figure out what page I need to include. That is pretty much it. There are a few micro-frameworks that have been suggested to me like [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) that is supposed to work well for this stuff.

Comment: oh ok..Thanks.  Can you answer this as an answer so I can close out my question.  I'd rather accept your answer than delete the question or leave the question unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the only best way is to just set a constant/variable at the top level and refer to that. Most larger programs do this as it is the most reliable way to find the actual document root. Usually this is set in an installer. I generally bootstrap all my apps and just set a constant there.

I generally write a new setup based on what I'm doing. I just add a .htaccess file with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

in the root of my app. That will route all requests, whether the page exists or not to index.php. Then I setup a few variables, include a config file, connect to db and stuff like that. Then parse the url to figure out what page I need to include. That is pretty much it.

Also, static things like javascript, css or images, I just put into a public folder (usually in their own folder by type) and add an htaccess file with

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

So those files don't get routed through index.php. It is just overhead otherwise. You could change the rule in the first htaccess file to not include those files, but I just find it easier to use two separate.

There are a few micro-frameworks that have been suggested to me like [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) that is supposed to work well for this stuff.